# How does a worklight authentication adapter connects to backend?

Tags: worklight-adapters

How does connection establishes between a worklight authentication adapter and backend? Does adapter connects to backend when authentication fails?

Comment: Read : https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/authentication-security/adapter-based-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

An application sends a request to the server to call an adapter procedure that sends a request to the backend.

The adapter request will not attempt connecting to a backend if the authentication test has failed. Read more about adapters:

- https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/server-side-development-category/adapter-framework-overview/
- https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/authentication-security/adapter-based-authentication/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.In the documentation shared, a diagram depicts that worklight server checks if user authenticated or not. In that case a connection was already there before authentication right? Can you please explain that part?

Comment: Please read the authentication tutorials: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/authentication-security/